# Technique for Removing Duplicates Not Working (R)

Tags: r, duplicates, na, data-manipulation

I tried a method to remove duplicates and I'd love to know why it doesn't work.

Take this dataframe:

```
o<-c(123,123,123,124,125,126)
c<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
d<-c(8,8,NA,8,8,8)
df<-data.frame(o,c,d)
un<-unique(df$o)
df<-df[un,]
df
```

Now df is all NA's. Can someone tell me why????

***Side note*** in my real dataset (private info, hence the sample df): this same code DIDN'T generate NA's for all values. I noticed a problem as something like the following would happen: `length(df$var)=100, length(unique(df$var))=90`. Fine. Then I would run that above code (re-writing the df), and I'd see: `length(df$var)=90, length(unique(df$var))=80`. If I kept looping, I'd eventually end up with one row of all NA's.

I tried to replicate this error but the code that attempts to remove duplicates just generated all NA's, unlike in my real dataset. In any case, I'm hoping that discovering the problem in the code will answer my question.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try `df[df$o %in% un,]` instead of `df[un,]`

Comment: Line 6 of your code says "make a subset of df using rows 123, 124, 125 and 126." Which do not exit, hence the NA. But ir's not clear what you want to do when you say "remove duplicates". Can you show the desired output?

Comment: I see. The reason it was hard to catch in my original dataset is that the range of the variable I wanted to remove duplicates encompassed the number of rows in the df. Now that I'm looking over my sample dataset, I realize that duplicates in one variable were actually duplicates across all variables in a row (my sample df's rows are all unique combinations, so I guess technically my desired output would be the original df). But now I understand what was wrong with my indexing. Thanks for writing out Line 6 in words; that was really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your original data frame

```
> df<-data.frame(o,c,d)
> df
   o c  d
1 123 1  8
2 123 2  8
3 123 3 NA
4 124 4  8
5 125 5  8
6 126 6  8
```

Remove duplicate in the column "o"

```
>df[!duplicated(df[,c("o")]),]
    o c d
 1 123 1 8
 4 124 4 8
 5 125 5 8
 6 126 6 8
```

Remove duplicate in the column  "d"

```
>df[!duplicated(df[,c("d")]),]
    o c  d
 1 123 1  8
 3 123 3 NA
```

Comment: Your second chunk of code worked perfectly for what I want to do. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
un_logical <- !duplicated(df$o)
df<-df[un_logical,]
```

Have you checked what `un` is after you create it?  As per [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/unique), `unique` returns the unique *elements*, not *indices to the unique elements*.  In your example, `un == c(123,124,125,126)`, which are very much out of range of rows of `df`.

If the column you are searching in your real dataset is similarly integers in this general range, then your real dataset is probably long enough that the unique elements found by `unique` are real indices.